# Update my ethernet driver Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller

Tags: windows-10, networking, drivers, updates

So I want to manually update my Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller driver. According to Windows update it has the latest version but it's from 2016-04-22. I want to update it because I got a gigabit connection but I'm only averaging 550-650 mbps, so updating my driver might solve the issue. If someone knows anything else that might be causing my internet to be bottlenecked please feel free to give suggestions.

I went on their website but I don't know which version to download since it seems to be a different than what I have. I have version 10.9.422.2016. I went to their [website](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-pci-express-software), but I don't what I should be downloading. I'm on Windows 10.

What confuses me the most is that I went to many other websites and I'm getting different drivers versions in every one. Maybe it's because there are different hardware version of Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller? If so how could I check for my hardware version? Maybe I already have the latest update.

Comment: There are multiple different Realtek GBE Card hardware, so its probable that your driver is no longer supported.  That said, don't bother with new firmware - Realtek cards are known for crap performance - they are badly designed in ways firmware can't fixed.  Get yourself another card and use that instead.  I have had a great run with Intel cards.

Comment: I checked in the driver properties and I can theoretically achieve 1gigabit that's why I was asking. I have a laptop so changing it is out of the question. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: The vendor of the laptop may have specific drivers.  Assume you have checked their website for drivers.  I have found Windows Update drivers can be problematic as OEMs can slightly modify the driver needed for "their" chipset

Comment: @DaveM I had forgotten about this post (I just gave up on the issue because I wasted a lot of time on it without getting anywhere). So I just checked my driver's version and it's apparently 10.46.1231.2020, which is newer than what I had in my post. But then I went as you suggested to asus' website (my laptop is an asus rog), and for some reason their newest driver for my laptop series is still the one I had when I made my post. I don't even remember updating my driver, and if I did I forgot where I got this new version from, which is bizarre since asus does not offer a newer version.

Comment: Anyway even after having a new version, this didn't solve my issue and I'm still averaging 600mbps (which is probably why I stopped trying to fix the issue at the time since updating didn't do anything). Thank you anyway!